# Weird rendering issues on android devices

Tags: android, css, mobile

I'm getting a issue with the image background repeating(see image).  Even though i have set the CSS property to no-repeat.  The source is http://www.pcpal.co.uk/mobile/

PS sorry about the image being so big.

also is there any good tools/resources I can use as i'm new to creating a mobile site..

[image: Image from my iphone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own issue in the end.  I removed a comma from my CSS code..

```
background-position: 5px, center;
```

to

```
background-position: 5px center;
```

Many Thanks to those who took the time to read my problem